# Java Operand error when using inheritance, but not when doing the same thing on a single class

Tags: java

First off, YES this is homework (But I am doing the work on my own). I have been working my tail off, but I'm failing to understand what I am doing wrong.

The assignment is requesting two classes for a sales persons base salary and for a commission.

I'm sure you have seen this before, but I cannot find other posts with this issue.

My base salary class.

```
package salescommission;

public class SalesBaseSalary {

    public SalesBaseSalary() {

        int baseSalary = 75000;

    }
}
```

AND my Sales commission class

```
package salescommission;

//Adding Scanner Utility
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SalesCommission extends SalesBaseSalary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner input
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int totalSales;
        int salesPlusSalary;

        //input commissions        
        System.out.print( "Enter Annual Commissions" );
        totalSales = input.nextInt();

        salesPlusSalary = (int) (totalSales * .05 + SalesBaseSalary);

        System.out.printf( "Sales commission plus Salary is %d\n", salesPlusSalary );  
    }
}
```

NOW if I do this as one class, it works perfectly... but I have to have two.  This is the single class.

```
package salescompensation;

//Adding Scanner Utility
import java.util.Scanner;

//Main Class representing the employees base salary
public class SalesCompensation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner input
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int totalSales;
        int salesPlusSalary;
        //base salary    
        double baseSalary = 75000;    
        //input commissions        
        System.out.print( "Enter Annual Commissions" );
        totalSales = input.nextInt();

        salesPlusSalary = (int) (totalSales * .05 + baseSalary);

        System.out.printf( "Sales commission plus Salary is %d\n", salesPlusSalary );

    }

}
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and WHY so I can learn.

Comment: What makes you think you are doing something wrong? Perhaps that would provide valuable clues ... (no we are no going to debug your code, and guess what aspect of its behaviour or compilation you might be wondering about)

Comment: Therefore, if you have a compiler error **post the error**. If your see strange runtime behaviour, **describe the behaviour**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend sheltem's answer, you should get the field from an *instance* of the `SalesCommission` class (assuming that it is not a class constant).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   // Create an instance of the SalesCommission class (an object)
   SalesCommission salesCommission = new SalesCommission();

   //Scanner input
   Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
   int totalSales;
   int salesPlusSalary;

   //input commissions        
   System.out.print( "Enter Annual Commissions" );
   totalSales = input.nextInt();

   salesPlusSalary = (int) (totalSales * .05 + SalesCommission.baseSalary);

   System.out.printf( "Sales commission plus Salary is %d\n", salesPlusSalary );  
}
```

Also since you're just getting the hang of Java, OOP and classes etc., I recommend you work through [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) or other similar resources and review your design and how you can make it better. By striving to improve you'll learn OOP and good design/practices.

Comment: I have been using PluralSight for the past 3 days... that is how I was able to get to... where I am at.

Comment: Ok.  So, from yours and sheltems responses (thanks btw, i'm working threw this).  Ok... sheltem is correct, I forgot to mention that I was receiving a runtime error on that specific line "salesPlusSalary = (int) (totalSales * .05 + SalesBaseSalary);"  I later realized that I needed to adjust baseSalary < SalesCommission.baseSalary.  " SalesCommission salesCommission = new SalesCommission();" I realize I need this but I am unsure why... is this what is creating the instance?

Comment: @user3295155 this is why I recommend you go through the Java tutorial I provided a link to. Java is a Object Orientated Programming (OOP) language and you need to become familiar with thinking in those terms if you want to truly understand what is going on.

Comment: @user3295155 also please mark sheltem's answer as correct. This is good practice on StackOverflow to mark the answer that helps you/answers your question as correct.

Comment: OK just thought I would share... Thanks for the help.  I had multiple problems, that I was able to sort threw due to inexperience.. (i know.. your "not going to debug my code" and provide "valuable clues")  I took my main function out of my class and put it in its own class.  I should have been using Double instead of Int... and netbeans was a little sensitive with the compiling.  I just //commented off the line (which was identified by sheltem (thanks again).  compiled. it worked... so once I fixed that line... by compiling one class at a time... and fixing my "formalities" (thanks xlm)

Comment: @user3295155 I'm always happy to help, as are others on StackOverflow. I think your points about 'not going to debug my code' etc. happens when newer users don't take the effort to properly explain or ask their question which makes it harder for us to help :) Keep improving, you'll get there, remember we were all in your situation at some point in our career.

Answer (score 1):

```
salesPlusSalary = (int) (totalSales * .05 + SalesBaseSalary);
```

This line is the main problem.

You are trying to add a class (SalesBaseSalary) to a double. The class is not one of its fields, you'd have to access that (via e. g. `new SalesBaseSalary().baseSalary` or a getter).

For that to work though, you'd also have to declare the field outside of the constructor, otherwise it does not exist outside of the constructor's scope:

```
public class SalesBaseSalary {

    int baseSalary;

    public SalesBaseSalary()
    {
        baseSalary = 75000;
    }
```

(Edit: just saw that SalesBaseSalary is the superclass of SalesCommission, so in that case you will be able to access its non-private fields directly, but they still have to exist outside of the constructor.)

Comment: +1 for helping answer his question. Whilst I appreciate him marking my answer correct, you too deserve rep.

Comment: I apologize, still getting used to this webpage... You BOTH helped me, and technically you BOTH had points that elevated my ability to get a resolution.  I cannot mark both correct though... and I also cannot +1 anybody...

Comment: @user3295155 That's alright, I thought the previous arrangement was pretty good i.e. mark mine correct and I +1 sheltem.

Comment: Don't worry about who's marked correct and whatnot, the important part is that your problem got solved. Glad we could help. ;)